# definition of a point inside a domain

Tags: general-topology, geometry

If given a point P in $ R^{3} $ and a closed domain $ \Omega$, how do I mathematically define is the point is inside or outside the domain.

I am looking for a mathematical statement to explicitly say whether the point is inside or outside the domain without invoking any other definition. Also, I am aware of Jordan's curve theorem and am looking for any other alternative statement without means of any ray projection or sort.

[Point inside and outside domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grJnE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could compute the distance $d(x,A)$. If it is positive, the point $x$ lies outside the set $A$. If $d(x,A^c)>0$, then $x$ lies inside $A$. This algorithm works for any metric space. By $A^c$ I mean the complement of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it could fit your needs, but a possibly handy definition involves distance.
For example $$\bar {d}(P, \Omega) = \min_{x \in \Omega} d(P,x)$$ where $d$ stands for a euclidean distance between points.

Then, if $P \in \Omega$ it follows that $\bar{d} = 0$; otherwise, $\bar{d} \neq 0$

Comment: If two persons think independently about the same approach, it should be good. :)

Comment: If you knew me, you would maybe not think so! Just joking,

Comment: This definition works but would you able to define it in terms of limits ? Could I define a ball of radius $ \epsilon $ around my point and say that the point lies inside the domain if for some $\delta > 0$ , limit $ \epsilon \to \delta $ $ dom(B(\epsilon)) - dom(\Omega) = \phi $

Comment: @Adi279, I am afraid I do not entirely get your point, what does $dom$ stand for exactly?

Comment: My apologies. I meant domain though it is not necessary to write dom. If I were to define an euclidean ball about point P and let the radius $ \epsilon $ tend to some positive value $ \delta > 0 $ , then if the point is inside the domain, the set difference would result in a null set. Otherwise, if the point is outside the domain, then for any $ \delta > 0 $ the set difference would never result in a null set . I don't think this definition works, but I am looking for a similar definition. I was also thinking to define if $ \epsilon \to 0^{+} $ , $B(\epsilon,P) \bigcup \Omega \to \Omega$

Comment: If your point is inside the domain, it seems to me $\epsilon$ should $\to$ 0, not a positive $\delta$ ($\delta$ should be less that the distance between $P$ and $\partial \Omega$, is not it?).